# How to use conditional statement with Postman's new pm.* API?

Tags: testing, postman, chai

I have a question about how to use the new pm.* API with conditional statements. Please take a look at the following example code

```js
if(pm.test("Status code is 200", function({
   pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.equal(300);})){
    
   var token = pm.response.headers.get("Authorization");
   pm.environment.set("JWT Token", token.substr(7));
    
   pm.test("Response body is empty ", function () {
      pm.expect(pm.response.text().length).to.equal(0);
   });
}

console.log(pm.test("Status code is 200", function() {pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.equal(300)}));
```

As I may want to perform certain tests e.g. only when 200 is returned I wanted to use if. However, when I deliberately changed the equal value to 300 just to check if this works, both tests are run and the variable is set, even though the first test fails.

The console.log returns an empty object instead of true/false for the assertion. And if I use something like

```js
console.log(pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.equal(300));
```

I'll get an error message:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  AssertionError: expected 200 to equal 300

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Cheers

Comment: I would say that your last console.log result is normal as assertion is false, however, it's quite strange that the test as the beginning passes ... have you tried to put a console log just below pm.environment.set, to see if you really go there ?

Comment: other question : what's the behaviour with classic postman syntax ?

Comment: @A.Joly This is my old test script using the JS that I'm trying to move to new pm.* API.

    `if(tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200) {

    var token = postman.getResponseHeader("Authorization");
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("JWT Token", token.substr(7));
    
    tests["Body is empty"] = responseBody.length === 0;
    
}`.   

I also tried putting the console.log below, but to no avail.
Edit: Sorry, I seem to be super bad at comment's formatting

Comment: :)  can't you edit your own post ?

Comment: Only for 5 minutes, sadly! Meanwhile I still haven't got a clue why this doesn't work as I'd expect it to

Comment: I'm not sure you can use pm.test as a condition for further processing in fact ... :(

Answer (score 14):

I have also asked this question on a Postman's github and I've got help. Apparently pm.test does not return the result of the test because you can have multiple assertions in one pm.test and those are executed asynchronously.

Following code works as expected:

```js
pm.test("Status code is 200", function() {
   pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.equal(200);
});
    
(pm.response.code===200 ? pm.test : pm.test.skip)("Response body is empty", function () {
  pm.expect(pm.response.text().length).to.equal(0);
        
  var token = pm.response.headers.get("Authorization");
  pm.environment.set("JWT Token", token.substr(7));
});
```

Comment: WTH is that response from postman github...
I mean, thanks for sharing your knowledge, and thanks to the guys who took some time to answer, but I 'm really questioning that choice from postman team.
As far as I can see, there is a RED / GREEN flag next to each PM.TEST() in the collection runner, then we should be able to extract at some point a boolean showing the global result of it... Who cares if the PM.EXPECTs are run asynchronously... Even better, you can add a "RETURN" statement at the end of the PM.TEST() block, but it's NOT reachable from the outside

Answer (score 2):

If all you're looking to do here is skip the remaining tests if the response code is something other than 200, you could do the following:

```js
pm.test("Status code is 200", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.equal(200);
});

if (pm.response.code !== 200) {
    return;
}

// Tests that require 200 could continue here
```