# Add if else verification in POSTMAN test script

Tags: testing, automated-tests, postman

I am creating a test case where I am expecting to pass the test if response code is 200, and if it's not 200 then check for response code as 500 and "error_msg": "token失效,请重新登录". If this is true then test is passed, but if any other error msg is generated test fails.

```
{
    "code": "lid5000294001",
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "error_msg": "token失效,请重新登录"
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-05-03 14:52:05",
    "traceId": "c92e2e2f679a4cd893bb6980134247ef"
}
```

Please suggest what shall be added in the test script? Currently I am only having

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use conditional statement with Postman's new pm.\* API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929974/how-to-use-conditional-statement-with-postmans-new-pm-api)

Comment: This does not help, I have checked that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would be:

```js
if (pm.response.code === 500) {
    pm.test("Status code is 500", function () {
        const res = pm.response.json();
        pm.expect(res.data.error_msg).eql("token失效,请重新登录")
    });

} else {
    pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
      pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirement in my case I followed the following steps:-

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var env_var = pm.environment.get("token_status");
if (env_var === "active") {
    pm.test(`Status code is 200`, () => {
        pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    })
}
else {
    pm.test(`Status code is 500`, () => {
        pm.response.to.have.status(500);
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.error_msg).to.equal("token失效,请重新登录");
        //pm.response.body.("token失效,请重新登录");
        //pm.response.to.have.("token失效,请重新登录");
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).